# Vue2 directive and click throws undefined (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I am trying to make a directive in Vue2 in TypeScript and so far everything was okay until I wanted to make a button clickable.

Here's the code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MyDirective extends Vue
{
    private element:HTMLElement;
    private binding:any;

    public inserted(element:HTMLElement, binding:any):void
    {
        // core parameters
        this.element = element;
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    public onSubmit():void
    {
        console.log('submitted!');
    }
}
```

And in the HTML I call it this way

```
<div v-my-directive>
    <a href="" @click="onSubmit"></a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it throws an error

```
Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined
```

When I change `@click="onSubmit"` to `@click="onSubmit()"`, error is a bit different

```
onSubmit is not a function
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Your component class is `MyDirective` but you're referencing `v-my-component` in the markup, that doesn't look correct to me, should it be `v-my-directive`?

Comment: @Sly_cardinal thank you for pointing this out. Yes it was a typo made only in this example, however problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here which are causing your problem.

1. You are registering `MyDirective` with the `@Component` annotation, but directives need to be registered with `Vue.directive('my-directive', {...})`.
2. Functions on directives are not available outside that directive. You would either need to define the `onSumbit()` function in the parent component or inside a custom component of your own.

This shows that `onSubmit` should actually be defined by the **parent component**:

```
<div v-my-directive>
    <!--
    onSubmit defined in `my-directive` is not accessible in this location
    
    onSubmit function needs to be defined in the outer component that 
    has this part of the template (not the directive).
    -->
    <a href="" @click="onSubmit"></a>
</div>
```

[The documentation indicates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) that directives are designed for low-level DOM interaction:

> Note that in Vue 2.0, the primary form of code reuse and abstraction is components - however there may be cases where you just need some low-level DOM access on plain elements, and this is where custom directives would still be useful

What you are trying to achieve should be done with a component instead of a directive.

**Option 1:** Define a custom component with its own `onSubmit` function

```
<div>
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>


// Define `onSubmit` inside a component with its own template
@Component({
    template: '<a href="" @click="onSubmit"></a>'
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue
{
    public onSubmit():void
    {
        console.log('submitted!');
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** Define a custom component and pass the `onSubmit` function to the component

```
<div>
    <my-component on-submit="onSubmit"></my-component>
</div>


// Pass `onSubmit` to the component
@Component({
    props: {
        onSubmit: Function
    },
    template: '<a href="" @click="onSubmit"></a>'
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue
{
    
}
```

Directives are designed for lower-level access, like adding event listeners directly to DOM elements.